# How to define a route in rails hiding information like ids in urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had just started ruby on rails and i am not getting how to hide ids in urls, so that it won't be visible to user

For example for creating a new user, the route will be

> users/new

And for editing an existing user, route should be -

> users/:id/edit

But id is an unnecessary detail to user. So how we can hide it from users and what will be the new route.

Comment: You need a gem like this which I think is a better option: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: can we do it without any gem??

Comment: You can, check this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url-revised?view=asciicast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two perspective to this problem.

The first perspective is that of a user. I'm assuming you're talking about a user editing his own profile. In this case, the ID is indeed redundant. I recommend you handle this use case by adding a resource named `profile` and the corresponding `ProfilesController`. In `config/routes.rb` add:

```
resource :profile, only: [:show, :update]
```

**Note it reads `resource`, not `resources`**.

The second perspective is that of an administrator. In this case, it's better to use `resources` (not `resource`) so that the administrator is able to edit *any* user he wishes. On top of that, the administrator may have some extra capabilities that regular users lack (for example: making someone an admin).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have some unique identifier in the url.  However, this unique identifier does not have to be the auto incremented id generated by your database.  If you have ensured uniqueness on another field (say username), you could use that as the part of your route.

```
users/:username/edit
```

Using [This link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters), we can see that the resources definition in the routes can be done for all the routes in one line

```
resources :users, param: :username
```

Your `UsersController` would look something like this

```
class UsersController
  ...

  def edit
    @user = User.where(username: params[:username]).first
    ...
  end
end
```

You can also set the `to_param` method on the model to the new identified `username`

```
class User
  ...

  def to_param
    username
  end

  ...
end
```

This will allow you to do

```
@user = User.where(username: "test123")
edit_user_path(@user) #=> /users/test123/edit
```

thanks to Simple Lime for pointing that out.

EDIT

The `new` route would be unchanged by this update.  It would still be

```
/users/new
```

Comment: It's mentioned in your link, but you aren't mentioning the `to_param` part on the model

Answer (score 0):

You can define post route
`post 'users/edit', to: user#edit`
and in edit method you can get id from `params`